# Calculating averages from a sequence of numbers with a header value

Tags: java

The file numbers.text consists of sequences of numbers, each sequence preceded by a header value and followed by that many integers. Read in the sequences and print their averages. When all sequences have been read in, print out the number of sequences processed.

For example, if the file *numbers.text* contains:

```
3 1 2 3
5 12 14 6 4 0
10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 17
2 90 80
```

The program should produce the following output:

```
The average of the 3 integers 1 2 3 is 2.0
The average of the 5 integers 12 14 6 4 0 is 7.2
The average of the 3 integers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 is 5.5
The average of the 1 integers 17 is 17.0
The average of the 2 integers 90 80 is 85.0
5 sets of numbers processed
```

My code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("numbers.text"));
     
    int count = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double avg = 0;
        double total = 0;  
        System.out.print("The average of the " + n + " integers ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print(x + " ");
            total += x;
        }
            
        avg = total / n;
        System.out.print("is " + avg + "\n");
        count++;
    }

    System.out.print(count + " sets of numbers processed");
}
```

I don't know why the last line for sets of numbers processed isn't printing and why after 85.0 is printed, a new line is missing. There's also an exception in thread "main" `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and note that when asking about exceptions you should post the stacktrace as well and point out which lines of the code you've posted are mentioned there.

Comment: Try `sc.hasNextInt()` instead of `sc.hasNextLine()`.

Comment: Typical troubleshooting in scenarios like this would be: Look at the stack trace. Which specific line of your code throws the exception? Which methods are you calling on this line? Google "<method name> api" and you will often find javadoc documentation, [like here, for Scanner.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Read the documentation there. This documentation specifies that NoSuchElementException is thrown if input is exhausted. This could cause you to start thinking about "what is the input after having read the last '80'" token from the input?".